# Creating a list of regex matches from a data frame in Python and then counting the number of matches

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to

-match the number of times a dollar/cent/percent appears in a column in a data frame  -create a function that lists all of these matches  -create a function that  count the number of matches

I'm able to successfully use regex to find the matches, but I'm unable to get a list to appear and count them. I tried using `str.extract()` to list out all of the matches and `str.contains().sum()` to count the number of matches. However, I can't get these to work at the same time and I'm not sure if this is even the right approach.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(?:^|\s)(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)
```

This will match any dollar/cent or percent, and accounts for a bunch of different typos that I'm trying to include so the regex string is fine.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

sample_csv = pd.DataFrame({'SMS_text': ['$1', '214-233-4455'],
                           'SMS_number': ['1', '1'],
                           'Amount': ['12.12%', '$10.12'],
                           'Percent': ['10%', '1']})

sample_csv.Amount.str.extract(r'(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)')
```

This will list out the matches from the Amount column.

```
0    12.12%
1    $10.12
Name: Amount, dtype: object
```

And if I substitute `str.extract()` with `sample_csv.Amount.str.contains(r'(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)').sum()` it will tell me how many matches there are (i.e. 2) but again, I can't get them to work at the same time.

Is this the right approach or am I setting this up wrong? Seems like maybe a `findall()` or maybe an `re.compile()` might work better, but I'm not sure how to get these to work properly.

My desired output from above would be something like:

```
regex_number_matches = ['12.12%', '$10.12']
regex_number_matches_count = 2
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you want the number of times % or $ appears in the dataframe?

Comment: Okay, I will rephrase it. Here's what I want:

(1) find a specific regex match in a dataframe (i.e. all dollars/cents/percents)
(2) list every instance of that regex match in output
(3) count the total amount of those matches in output

Comment: @David, can you post your desired data set?

Answer (score 2):

If you want total number of times % or $ appears in your dataframe, try

```
sample_csv.stack().str.contains('%|\$').sum()
```

It returns 4

If you want all the instance of the cells in which those appear, try

```
sample_csv[sample_csv.stack().str.contains('%|\$').unstack()]
```

And you get

```
    Amount  Percent SMS_number  SMS_text
0   12.12%  10%     NaN         $1
1   $10.12  NaN     NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems (to me) you want to find those values in the `Amount` column that can't be converted to numbers:

Assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [107]: sample_csv
Out[107]:
   Amount Percent  SMS_number      SMS_text
0  12.12%     10%           1            $1
1  $10.12       1           1  214-233-4455
2    1.23       2           1  214-233-4455
3    33,5       3           1  214-233-4455
```

first create a boolean mask of those rows where Amount can't be converted to numeric value:

```
In [108]: mask = pd.to_numeric(sample_csv['Amount'], errors='coerce').isnull()

In [109]: mask
Out[109]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: Amount, dtype: bool
```

now you can easily filter DF, using this mask:

```
In [110]: sample_csv.loc[mask, 'Amount']
Out[110]:
0    12.12%
1    $10.12
3      33,5
Name: Amount, dtype: object

In [111]: sample_csv.loc[mask, 'Amount'].tolist()
Out[111]: ['12.12%', '$10.12', '33,5']

In [112]: len(sample_csv.loc[mask, 'Amount'])
Out[112]: 3
```

Comment: I'm working with a large csv that contains a bunch of text/sentence entries and I'm trying to tease out any dollars/cents/percents. So I'm not trying to convert anything into a numeric value, I'm just trying to pull out $ and % from the text/sentences.

Is there a way to do this without creating a boolean mask or do you think this is a good approach? It's a bit above my head so the simpler the better for me.

Comment: @David, and how did you get/parse `Amount` column?

Comment: I just used sample_csv.Amount.str.extract(r'(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)') to pull out any regex matches from the Amount column

Comment: @David, i'm trying to understand whether you're fishing for "dollars/cents/percents" in a free text or from a column like `Amount` (it doesn't look like a free text). Adding more different samples for parsing could help...

Comment: The column will contain things like this in practice:
`'Amount': ['Hi there, you earned a bonus of 12.12%, keep it up!', 'Your daily payout is $10.12', 'Great it was nice speaking with you today!', Make sure your balance is more than $100.50', 'Have a great day!]`

So the output I'm looking for would be something like:
12.12%

Comment: So the output I'm looking for would be something like:
`12.12%
$10.12
$100.50`

`total = 3`

Comment: then just extract matching substrings first into a Series/array/list and then simply get the length of that list - you don't need to search using RegEx for a second time...

Comment: I guess that's what I'm not sure about. How would I go about doing this? Thanks for all of your help btw